# CSS Nav - last item not aligning properly

Tags: css, html-lists, nav

Link: http://danhumphrey.co.uk/nav/

As you can see the last item isn't working correctly if you hover over the last item you'll only get half the box.

I've tried playing around with the padding and margin of the `li`, `h2` and `a` and been unsuccessful.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: In which browser and version are you having the problem? I tried it in Firefox and is ok (in Safari 3 I can only see the first item)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with fixed width of  make some css changes as below:

```
nav {
 height: auto;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 23px auto 0;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 23px;
 height: 29px;

}
ul#headNav {
 padding: 0px 0 0 0;
 display: inline-block;
 background: #7F7C74;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7F7C74 0%, #94918A 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#7F7C74), color-stop(100%,#94918A));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7F7C74 0%,#94918A 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #7F7C74 0%,#94918A 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #7F7C74 0%,#94918A 100%);
background: linear-gradient(top, #7F7C74 0%,#94918A 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7f7c74', endColorstr='#94918a',GradientType=0 );
}
```

**Note:** I just removed `width:960px;` from `<nav>` & added `text-align:center` to it & moved all gradient CSS & `display:inline-block;` to `#headNav`

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/pZkk9/1/

Comment: @Dipaks Check the working fiddle in the answer http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/pZkk9/1/

Comment: You are doing too much - it's not required :)

Comment: @Dipaks Its required coz it will make things flexible & scalable

Answer (score 0):

You have defined inline `Width` to the last li element - `width: 40px;`

the Width is not necessary, you can remove it or if you need it for some reason then increase it to `width: 95px;` and it will work. Tested in Latest Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you change the background of the link which is in front of the grey bar, but not as wide. You have several options:

- Fix the width of the menu items and make sure they add up to the correct width (possibly including borders) or
- Set all backgrounds on the `a` elements (this way the size will naturally be the same)

Answer (score 0):

Delete the inline `style="width: 40px;"` and add this line to your css:

```
nav ul li:last-child{width: 91px;}
```

Comment: last-child doesn't work in IE8 and what's the difference between my answer and your?

Comment: @Dipaks It's my own answer. After I submit it, I saw that your answer is similar to mine. I checked my answer with Opera. It works. Your answer is about `width: 90px;`, then you changed it to `width: 95px;`, but mine is not edited (`width: 91px;`). Another difference is `:last-child` as you mentioned! :)